How to Recover the .idea Folder in an Android Project?
I mistakenly deleted the .idea folder in my Android project through the Android Studio Git commit section under ignored files. Unfortunately, the folder did not go to the recycle bin. The .idea folder contained my Git shelves (local shelf) with essential app hacks that I've been working on (shelves for quick navigation through the app).

Currently, the Android Studio Explorer local history does not show any changes or shelves since the root folder was deleted. I've also tried recovering the folder on Windows 10, but system protection was turned off, so no system restore points or file history were created.
Is there any way to recover those patch files?

Restore them from a backup. You do back up your computer, right?
